# How to read a text file has UTF-16 LE encoding in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I tried with this code it says UnicodeDecodeError.

```
base_file =open(textfiles[i], encoding='utf-16-le')
text = base_file.read()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError when reading a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777370/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-a-text-file)

Comment: Use `utf_16_le` or `UTF-16LE`. From [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)